# Elastic HeartBeat configured to capture change status

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I was wondering if it is possible to configure the elastic heartbeat to only send data when there is a real status change on events.

If a host is always pingable I would avoid to fill up my buffer queue with useless data, instead whenever it turns to unreachable I'd love if it could sent one message with new status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beats are collecting time series data. This event data is being stored in elasticsearch indices alongside the event's timestamp and other metadata.
So if you change the behaviour in the asked way, there will be no event data for some timespans.
And now imagine a dashboard/query, where you want to have a look on a specific timeframe and no data is present at all.

But there is a second reason. The availability status is not the only information being collected. Take the response times, status codes and other metadata into account. Even if there is no change in the avaiability of the monitored service, there can be valuable changes in the metadata.

This was the explanation why we store all the events and the answer on our question is no, it's not possible.

Comment: I got this, beats are created and designed to collect time series data not for any other purpose. I was just hoping in a configuration that could fit my needs. +1